# BackTrack 5 R3 LiveUSB is not working on my Lenovo G50 70

Tags: lenovo-laptop, backtrack

I've created a LiveUSB of BackTrack 5 r3 using Unetbootin.  When I tried to run it on my Lenovo G50 70 laptop, it shows an error like "kernel panic not syncing attempted to kill init".  But when I use the same USB stick on an HP Pavilion 2000, it works perfectly.  Both are 64-bit architecture laptops and I created a 64-bit BackTrack OS.  The difference between the two laptops is Lenovo is using Win 8.1 and HP is using Win 7.

What should I do to run BackTrack 5 rather than Kali Linux?

Comment: If You haven't done it yet, do a google search for the error and find something like this:
https://www.deep-silver.com/kernel-panic-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init/

Comment: Im pretty sure you have to change a setting that puts all of the input from your computer on to your virtual os